# Como puedo pasar datos de una pagina a otra mediante ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html5, ajax

```
</head>
<body>

        <form action="llega.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha">
        <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion">
        <input type="submit" name="enviar">
        <button id="enviar"><a href="llega.php">Enviar</button>
    </form>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="envia.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Mediante ajax enviamos las variables

```
 $("#enviar").click(function(){

    fecha =$("#fecha").val();
    direccion =$("#direccion").val();

    console.log(fecha,direccion);

              var datos = new FormData();

            datos.append("fecha", fecha);
            datos.append("direccion",direccion );

            $.ajax({

                url:"llega.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: datos,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(respuesta){

    }

        });

    });
```

Las variables llegan a llega.php pero estas no llegan algun idea de como pasarlas sin usar un metodo get

```
<?php

echo $_POST["direccion"];
echo $_POST["fecha"];

?>
```

Comment: ¿Necesitas navegar a la segunda pagina?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes quitar la etiqueta form:

```
<input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha">
<input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion">
<button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
```

Ajax quedaría asi:

```
$("#enviar").click(function(){

fecha =$("#fecha").val();
direccion =$("#direccion").val();

        $.ajax({

            url:"proceso.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                direccion: direccion,
                fecha: fecha,
            },
            success: function(respuesta){
                window.location.href = 'llega.php';
            }

    });

});
```

Debes crear un archivo llamado proceso.php y en el escribir este código:

```
<?php

  session_start();
  $_SESSION['DIRECCION']  = $_POST["direccion"];
  $_SESSION['FECHA'] = $_POST["fecha"];

?>
```

Y en el archivo llega.php pones:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  echo $_SESSION['DIRECCION'];
  echo $_SESSION['FECHA'];
?>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos

Comment: asi funciona, pero mi pregunta seria ahora es posible hacerlo sin variables session

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a utilizar ajax indicando la URL, en el form del HTML no hace falta que pongas el `action`, puede crear conflicto. Y otra cosa, porque tienes un input tipo `submit` y luego un botón que llama a la pagina `todollega.php`. Quita el botón y quédate con el submit:

```
<form>
     <input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha">
     <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion">
     <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

El form no hace falta, porque podria causar conflicto con el ajax, asi como el input submit y el href son innecesarios, tan solo con esto te serviria:

```
        <input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha">
        <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion">
        <button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
```

otra cosa que debes ajustar es el ajax:

```
$("#enviar").click(function(){

fecha =$("#fecha").val();
direccion =$("#direccion").val();

        $.ajax({

            url:"llega.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                direccion: direccion,
                fecha: fecha,
            },
            success: function(respuesta){

            }

    });

});
```

Y ya con eso el PHP que tienes recoge las variables del ajax.